# How do I generate the rest authorization token for cosmos db in python?

Tags: python, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having trouble generating the authorization token for cosmos db for a simple get databases request. Here is my python code:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime

key = 'AG . . .EZPcZBKz7gvrKiXKsuaPA=='
now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:00 GMT')
payload = ('get\ndbs\n\n' + now + '\n\n').lower()
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key, msg = payload, digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

url = 'https://myacct.documents.azure.com/dbs'
headers = {
    'Authorization': "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + signature,
    "x-ms-date": now,
    "x-ms-version": "2017-02-22"
}

res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print res.content
```

Which produces this error:

```
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\ndbs\n\nsun, 08 apr 2018 02:39:00 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 5abe59d8-f44e-42c1-9380-5cf4e63425ec, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.0.0"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greg. Per my observe, the miss of your code is `url encode`. You could find the sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN#constructkeytoken).

Please refer to my code which was made a slight adjustment to your code.

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import urllib

key = '***'
now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:00 GMT')
print now
payload = ('get\ndbs\n\n' + now + '\n\n').lower()

payload = bytes(payload).encode('utf-8')
key = base64.b64decode(key.encode('utf-8'))

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key, msg = payload, digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
print signature

authStr = urllib.quote('type=master&ver=1.0&sig={}'.format(signature))
print authStr

headers = {
    'Authorization': authStr,
    "x-ms-date": now,
    "x-ms-version": "2017-02-22"
}
url = 'https://***.documents.azure.com/dbs'
res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print res.content
```

Execute result:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I also found that my key needed to be base64 decoded.

Comment: Any way to call the service without datetime? I have 3rd party where all requests are formatted as RAW http request without any coding.

Comment: Update for python3:

from urllib.parse import quote ||
payload =  bytes(payload, encoding='utf8') ||
authStr = quote('type=master&ver=1.0&sig={}'.format(signature))
|| print(...)